# Problem with :form_for and having rails application on www.domain.com/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns, form-for

I have a rails application which is accessible on www.mydomain.com/rails/
Everything seems to be working, except form_for helper which genererates a form tag with action="/controller", instead of action="/rails/controller".

How could I solve that ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is the version of rails you are using ? And can you please explain when you say "form_for helper aint working?" . Are you getting some error? If you can show us some code then I can help better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `:url` key to `controller`:

```
form_for(object, :url => 'controller')
```

This will set the `action` of the generated `form` tag to the relative path "`controller`".